# Proof $P_{n}(7) ≡ 0 \pmod {19}$ for every $n∈N$ given $P_{n}$ formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification

Given
$$P_{0} = x + 12 $$
$$P_{1} = x^2-5x+5$$
$$P_{n} = xP_{n-2}(x) - P_{n-1}(x) $$

Prove $P_{n}(7) ≡ 0 \pmod {19}$ for every $n ∈ N$

And prove for every prime q, if $P_{2017} (x)$ is not congruent to $0 \pmod {q}$, --> $P_{2017} (x)$ has at most $2017$ roots % $q$

Comment: Did you mean $P_\color{red}1=x^2-5x+5$?  Can you see that $P_0(7)\equiv P_1(7)\equiv0\pmod{19}$?

Comment: yes! oops, thanks for pointing that out. Yes I can see that!

Comment: can you prove $P_n(7)\equiv0\pmod{19}$ by mathematical induction?

Comment: i got stuck on the inductive step. Basically I said $k=n+1$ and declared $P_{k}(7) = xP_{n-1}(x)-P_{n}(x)$ but I wasnt sure how do prove that expression is divisible by 19. Im trying to come up with a stronger hypothesis, but I'm not sure yet. EDIT - got part a, working on b